# Enlarging toolbar icons in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome, icons

Recently I have bought a new laptop (HP envy K212) and have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it (I'm not new to Linux and I have worked with it before), now in this new Ubuntu every thing I install has very small toolbar (including Matlab, teamveiwer, Qt, everything!!!) for example in notepad++ it's like this:

[image]

I have tried these:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_icons_size "large-toolbar"

in /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:
[Settings]
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu=16,16:gtk-large-toolbar=16,16
(with different numbers)
```

and I installed unity tweak tool and poured over all it's features, and also gconf-editor (There is a toolbar_icon_size there which is set to large-toolbar, but what is this large-toolbar?!)

normal nautilus toolbar is OK and the problem is just for installed apps.
Thanks in advance for your help.